# Checkbox selected randomly in Recyclerview when using notifyDatasetChange

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

Checkbox is selected randomly in Recyclerview when using `notifyDatasetChange`. Here is my code.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {    
    SplitObject object=splitObjects.get(position);
    holder.textView_memberName.setText(object.getMember_name());
    holder.textView_splitAmount.setText(amount/splitObjects.size()+"");
    if(holder.checkBox.isChecked())
    {
        Debug.e("checked"+position);
    }
    else
    {    
        Debug.e("Unchecked"+position);
    }
    holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });    
 }
```

I am not able to figure out why `notifyDataSetChanged` function is not working properly.

Comment: i think you need to use setOnCheckedChangeListener() for that not onClick()

Answer (score 3):

Use checkChangeListener instead of onClickListener

```
    holder. checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    //if true, your checkbox will be selected, else unselected
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(pass the boolean from your list);

    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                //set your object's last status
                yourarrayobject.setSelected(isChecked);
        }
    });
```

Comment: _pass the boolean from your list_ which values i have to pass

Comment: Once you click the checkbox its state changes right it must be stored in your list to make the check box stay checked even if you reload the list, so you must store the state of the checkbox in your list (Initially it will be false for all checkbox) and pass it every time you load the list so that previously selected checkbox stay checked.

Comment: I am using List data type and which have group member detail and amount of group which i have to divide amount  equally in selected member equally .By default all member is selected.If unchecked any member then it will be divide selected member. if possible  please send me some link or code

Answer (score 1):

I think check box selected when you scroll the recyleview,YOu can please ***Viewholder*** concept,So add `viewHolder.CheckBox.setChecked(isItemChecked);` to onBindViewHolder and it will work. You will have to replace isItemChecked with your logic of retrieving the actual state for the item at the position...

Comment: what is isItemChecked

Comment: that's Boolean values

Answer (score 0):

Your `notifyDataSetChanged()` needs to run on the UI Thread. I had faced similar difficulties where the adapter wasn't getting properly updated. Try doing this in your OnClickListener:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
}
```